# MongoDB: How do I aggregate the values for each field of an object into a set while keeping the field name?

Tags: aggregation-framework

Given a data structure that stores arbitrary tags as a key value pairs.

The field names of the tag object correspond to the keys and are therefore not known in advance.

How can I aggregate several such documents into one so that it contains a field for each tag with an array containing the occured values?

Input:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("6346826e3b4cd5a90b20b75b"),
    "tags" : {
        "planet" : "earth",
        "color" : "blue"
    }
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("634683723b4cd5a90b20b819"),
    "tags" : {
        "planet" : "earth",
        "color" : "green",
        "foo" : "bar"
    }
}


{
    "_id" : ObjectId("634683823b4cd5a90b20b829"),
    "tags" : {
        "foo" : "acme",
        "color" : "red",
        "xyz" : "1"
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("634684063b4cd5a90b20b87f"),
    "tags" : {
        "planet" : [ "earth" ],
        "color" : [ "blue", "green", "red" ],
        "foo" : [ "bar", "acme" ],
        "xyz" : [ "1" ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure to include any attempts you made to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        a: {
          $objectToArray: "$tags"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "group by expression",
      "field": {
        $push: "$a"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "field": {
        "$reduce": {
          "input": "$field",
          "initialValue": [],
          "in": {
            "$concatArrays": [
              "$$value",
              "$$this"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$field"
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$field.k",
      "v": {
        "$addToSet": "$field.v"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "m": [
        {
          "k": "$_id",
          "v": "$v"
        },
        
      ]
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      a: {
        "$arrayToObject": "$m"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: "$a"
    }
  },
  
])
```

Looks similar :)

```
[
  {
    "foo": [
      "bar",
      "acme"
    ]
  },
  {
    "planet": [
      "earth"
    ]
  },
  {
    "xyz": [
      "1"
    ]
  },
  {
    "color": [
      "green",
      "red",
      "blue"
    ]
  }
]
```

https://mongoplayground.net/p/kTa3awcKdB2

The "Stage by stage output" drop-down can help to understand how it works.